# Динамическая интернационализация в Django

Tags: django

***Вопрос теоретический***: можно ли динамически добавить разные языки на работающий сайт?

Например (*теоретически*), у меня есть модель, где пользователь может добавить язык, который не поддерживается по стандарту в Django. После создания записи с новым языком, администратор может добавить перевод, а затем опубликовать ссылку, для переключения на этот язык.

Возможно ли такое сделать? Или все языки, на которых должен показываться сайт, должны быть заранее определены в `settings.py` и скомпилированы?

Comment: Чисто теоретически ничего не мешает просто отказаться от встроенного механизма переводов Django и сделать всё своё

Comment: Не знаете, это сложно реализуется?

Comment: Может и несложно если понимать принципы работы переводов, но количества работы будет немало, тема слишком обширная для Stack Overflow

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: Возможно, можно что-то сделать и с имеющимся механизмом переводов, но, судя по всему, Django делалась с расчётом на заранее предопределённый программистами список языков и на переводы, сделанные ими же. Так что это скорее приведёт к куче костылей (из некоторых мыслей — читать настройки LANGUAGES и LANG_INFO из json-файла и перезапускать Django-сервер при каждом изменении этого файла). Возможно, кто-нибудь здесь ещё расскажет, как это всё можно провернуть, но лично я эту тему не изучал

Comment: Да, вот про перезапуск сервера тоже читал. И это было проблемным местом. _Идея костыля была в следующем_: Переопределяю метод save() у модели с языками, а именно, создаю новую папку с именем `lang_code` в `locale`, программно запускаю `compile messages` и в `settings.LANGUAGES` добавляю новый кортеж. По идее, все должно работать, но перезапуск сервера портит всю малину, перезаписывая `LANGUAGES` на значение, которое изначально ему было присвоено.

Comment: Спасибо про идею с json-файлом, поищу какие-нибудь материалы

Comment: С помощью [django-hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad) например теоретически можно, чтобы пользователь сам перевёл весь сайт.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev бегло проглядел год; если я правильно понял, оно работает только с заранее прописанным списком языков в настройках, а автору надо языки на лету создавать — см. предыдущий его вопрос (если я не прав, то это будет хорошо)

Comment: @andreymal ну тогда лучше на том же принципе писать своё. Таблица языков, таблица строк с внешним ключом на языки и шаблонный тег для выборки.

Comment: Действительно, языки нужно создавать на "лету". Спасибо за идеи, буду разбираться с этим